# What happens to Content Observer object after unregisterContentObserver() is called?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, contentobserver

When using a `ContentProvider` to manage the application's data access, it's possible to use a `ContentObserver` to monitor for changes in the `ContentProvider`.

To create a `ContentObserver` we need to create a new object, normally inside Activity's onResume() method. Then the `ContentObserver` object is registered to get callbacks when data identified by a given content URI changes.

```
private Google_AR_Observer googleARObserver = null;    

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    googleARObserver = new Google_AR_Observer(this);
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
        CONTENT_URI, 
        true, 
        googleARObserver);
}
```

Finally, inside the Activity's onPause() method, the previously registered `ContentObserver` that is no longer needed is unregistered.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(googleARObserver);
}
```

My question is: What happens to ContentObserver after being unregistered? Is it destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code especially `ContentObserver`class , you will find a method `releaseContentObserver()`which is called when you unregister any observer. This method internally holds the reference of `contentObserver`object (inside other inner class `Transport`) which gets assigned to **null** value . So basically you can say its destroyed as soon as you unregister it

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about ContentObserver - it is a basic Java object. So if there are no more references to it garbage collector will take care of destroying it.

Answer (score 1):

It is just another Java class, it is destroyed when there is no reference to the class.